# Request unlimited increase in local storage allocation from actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, local-storage, shared-objects

I have been researching the SharedObject local storage option for graphics and player state information in a game I am creating. It seems that if you put the number of bytes in the flush() method Flash will prompt the user to increase the amount of data they will allow to be stored locally with a slider to pick an amount. In studying FarmVille they have just implemented an option to decrease load times by doing this However...

they request the amount to be unlimited. Is there a parameter in flush(), or method for SharedObject, that lets you request a specific amount to increase, or for the aforementioned unlimited?

Comment: Hi John, as i can see, when you ask for more than 10Mo in the flush method, flash show the request window to ask for unlimited storage. Try mySharedObject.flush( 12000000 );

Comment: Thanks. I tested it in the player instead of the IDE and that's exactly what happened.